# Flip Multiple Images one after another after some Delay

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, css-transforms

In my website, I want to create a CSS animation where I am trying to flip multiple images one after another after 1sec delay, but it's not working. When the first images flips then second image should flip then thrid and so on

Like [this](https://codepen.io/piupiupiu/pen/YyxWpd/) but onload, Each image should flip one after another.
Suppose there are 4 Images 1st image flips with delay:0 then second image flips with delay:1 an so on till fourth Image with delay:4

javascript

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var rotateComplete = function() {
    with(target.style) {
      webkitAnimationName = MozAnimationName = msAnimationName = "";
    }
    target.appendChild(arr[0]);
    setTimeout(function(el) {
      with(el.style) {
        webkitAnimationName = MozAnimationName = msAnimationName = "rotator2";
      }
    }, 0, target);
  };

  var target = document.getElementById("rotator2");
  var arr = target.getElementsByTagName("a");

  target.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", rotateComplete, false);
  target.addEventListener("animationend", rotateComplete, false);
  target.addEventListener("MSAnimationEnd", rotateComplete, false);

}, false);
```

```css
#stage2 {
  margin: 2em auto 1em 50%;
  height: 240px;
  -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 0 50%;
  -moz-perspective: 1200px;
  -moz-perspective-origin: 0 50%;
  -ms-perspective: 1200px;
  -ms-perspective-origin: 0 50%;
}

#rotator2 a {
  position: absolute;
  left: -151px;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#rotator2 a img {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#rotator2 a:nth-child(1) img {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-120deg) translateZ(80px);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-120deg) translateZ(80px);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(-120deg) translateZ(80px);
}

#rotator2 a:nth-child(2) img {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(80px);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(80px);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(80px);
}

#rotator2 a:nth-child(3) img {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(80px);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(80px);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(80px);
}

#rotator2 a:nth-child(n+4) {
  display: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotator2 {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-120deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes rotator2 {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-120deg);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes rotator2 {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-120deg);
  }
}

#rotator2 {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  -ms-animation-duration: 2s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 1s;
}

#rotator2:hover {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -ms-animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div id="stage2">
  <div id="rotator2" style="-webkit-animation-name: rotator2; -moz-animation-name: rotator2; -ms-animation-name: rotator2;">
    <a href="1.jpg"><img src="img/1.jpg" width="280" alt ="1"></a>
    <a href="2.jpg"><img src="img/2.jpg" width="280" alt ="2"></a>
    <a href="3.jpg"><img src="img/3.jpg" width="280" alt ="3"></a>
    <a href="4.jpg"><img src="img/4.jpg" width="280" alt ="4"></a>
    <a href="5.jpg"><img src="img/5.jpg" width="280" alt ="5"></a>
    <a href="6.jpg"><img src="img/6.jpg" width="280" alt ="6"></a>
    <a href="7.jpg"><img src="img/7.jpg" width="280" alt ="7"></a>
    <a href="8.jpg"><img src="img/8.jpg" width="280" alt ="8"></a>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Here the 1st image is continuously fliping

Comment: Have you already some code? If yes it makes it easier for us if you provide us the already existing code.

Comment: So your issue is that the animation is repeating? Did you try `animation-fill-mode: forwards`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the js code but for delaying, you can use `animation-delay`, isn't?

Comment: Images are side by side and it should create a chain recation

Comment: @MalteKölle you can consider [this](https://codepen.io/piupiupiu/pen/YyxWpd/)

Comment: Kavel, the animation in the w3schools is different than your code. Is it on purpose? (Not just the timing but the rotation origin)

Comment: its not a problem @MoshFeu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, as I said, you can use `animation-delay`. The value will be

> (card index) * `animation-duration`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .flip-card {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: transparent;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      perspective: 1000px;
    }
    
    .flip-card-inner {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      transition: transform 0.6s;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
    
    .flip-card-front,
    .flip-card-back {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
    
    .flip-card-front {
      background-color: #bbb;
      color: black;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    
    .flip-card-back {
      background-color: #2980b9;
      color: white;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .flip-card .flip-card-inner {
      animation: rotate 3s .3s infinite;
    }
    
    .flip-card:nth-child(2) .flip-card-inner {
      animation-delay: .6s;
    }
    
    .flip-card:nth-child(3) .flip-card-inner {
      animation-delay: .9s;
    }
    
    .flip-card:nth-child(4) .flip-card-inner {
      animation-delay: 1.2s;
    }
    
    @keyframes rotate {
      0%, 60% {
        transform: rotateY(0);
      }
      10%, 50% {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Card Flip with Text</h1>
  <h3>Hover over the image below:</h3>

  <div class="cards">
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="flip-card-inner">
        <div class="flip-card-front">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card-back">
          <h1>John Doe</h1>
          <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
          <p>We love that guy</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="flip-card-inner">
        <div class="flip-card-front">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card-back">
          <h1>John Doe</h1>
          <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
          <p>We love that guy</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="flip-card-inner">
        <div class="flip-card-front">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card-back">
          <h1>John Doe</h1>
          <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
          <p>We love that guy</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="flip-card-inner">
        <div class="flip-card-front">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card-back">
          <h1>John Doe</h1>
          <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
          <p>We love that guy</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Update**

To run it infinite, the animation should calculated differently because it should take care for the back animation.

The calculation is

> 0.3s (flip animation) * 5 (4 cards + 1 more for delay between iteration) * 2 (back and forth) = 3s.
>
> So each "tick" is 10%. We want to flip it back just in the middle of the animation so it 50%. More 10% for the back animation tick.

Here is the lifecycle:

```
|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|

|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
Front w   w   w   w  Back w   w   w   w
 .3s .3s .3s .3s .3s .3s .3s .3s .3s .3s 
|_______________________________________|
                   3s
```

Comment: how to add an Infinite loop in this. After last first should flip, I tried                             
    `flip-card .flip-card-inner {
      animation: rotate .3s .3s forwards infinite;
    }` ,but this flips all together

Comment: It's a little more tricky. I just updated my answer. Hope it's clear enough.

Comment: I figured it out yesterday                                           `/* animation */
    .flip-card .flip-card-inner {
      
      animation: rotate 20.0s  forwards infinite  ;
    }
    
 /* adding delay for chain recation effect*/
    .flip-card:nth-child(2) .flip-card-inner {
      animation-delay: 5s;
    }
    
    .flip-card:nth-child(3) .flip-card-inner {
      animation-delay: 10s;
    }
    
    .flip-card:nth-child(4) .flip-card-inner {
      animation-delay: 15s;
    }`  I changed the delay between those cards

Comment: Great! Glad to hear.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use that code attached below HTML and CSS trick:

```
<div class="c-searchblock_loop">
            <div class="c-searchblock_loop-content">
                <div class="c-searchblock_chevron">
                    <svg class="c-icon">
                        <use xlink:href="https://www.subachahai.com/dist/assets/icons/icons-sprite.svg#icon-chevron"></use>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="c-searchblock_image -first">
                    <img src="https://www.subachahai.com/dist/assets/images/searchblock-1.png" alt="tools-1">
                </div>
                <div class="c-searchblock_image -back -second">
                    <img src="https://www.subachahai.com/dist/assets/images/searchblock-2.png" alt="tools-2">
                </div>
                <div class="c-searchblock_image -third">
                    <img src="https://www.subachahai.com/dist/assets/images/searchblock-3.png" alt="tools-3">
                </div>
                <div class="c-searchblock_image -back -fourth">
                    <img src="https://www.subachahai.com/dist/assets/images/searchblock-4.png" alt="tools-4">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.c-searchblock_chevron {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.c-searchblock_chevron, .c-searchblock_image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.c-searchblock_image.-first {
    -webkit-animation: loop 2s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1) infinite,loop-first 4s linear infinite;
    animation: loop 2s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1) infinite,loop-first 4s linear infinite;
}
.c-searchblock_image {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% -25px;
    transform-origin: 50% 50% -25px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.c-searchblock_chevron, .c-searchblock_image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.c-searchblock_image.-back.-second {
    -webkit-animation: loop-image-back 2s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1) infinite,loop-second 4s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1) infinite;
    animation: loop-image-back 2s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1) infinite,loop-second 4s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1) infinite;
}
.c-searchblock_image.-back {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% 25px;
    transform-origin: 50% 50% 25px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(
180deg);
    transform: rotateY(
180deg);
}
.c-searchblock_image.-third {
    -webkit-animation: loop 2s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1) infinite,loop-third 4s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1) infinite;
    animation: loop 2s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1) infinite,loop-third 4s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1) infinite;
}
.c-searchblock_image.-back.-fourth {
    -webkit-animation: loop-image-back 2s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1) infinite,loop-fourth 4s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1) infinite;
    animation: loop-image-back 2s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1) infinite,loop-fourth 4s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1) infinite;
}
.c-searchblock_image.-back {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% 25px;
    transform-origin: 50% 50% 25px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(
180deg);
    transform: rotateY(
180deg);
}
.c-searchblock.is-active .c-searchblock_footer,
.c-searchblock.is-active .c-searchblock_loop {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
    transform: translate(0)
}
.c-searchblock_loop {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    -webkit-perspective: 200px;
    perspective: 200px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
    transform: translateY(40px);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s cubic-bezier(.76, 0, .24, 1) .08s;
    transition: -webkit-transform .8s cubic-bezier(.76, 0, .24, 1) .08s;
    transition: transform .8s cubic-bezier(.76, 0, .24, 1) .08s;
    transition: transform .8s cubic-bezier(.76, 0, .24, 1) .08s, -webkit-transform .8s cubic-bezier(.76, 0, .24, 1) .08s
    margin: 50px auto;
}
.editMode .c-searchblock_loop {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none
}
.c-searchblock_loop-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-animation: loop 2s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1) infinite;
    animation: loop 2s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1) infinite
}
.c-searchblock_chevron,
.c-searchblock_image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
.c-searchblock_chevron {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center
}
.c-searchblock_chevron svg {
    fill: #fff;
    width: 120px;
    height: 110px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg)
}
@-webkit-keyframes loop {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        transform: rotateY(0deg)
    }
    25% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        transform: rotateY(0deg)
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        transform: rotateY(180deg)
    }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        transform: rotateY(180deg)
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(1turn);
        transform: rotateY(1turn)
    }
}
@keyframes loop {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        transform: rotateY(0deg)
    }
    25% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        transform: rotateY(0deg)
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        transform: rotateY(180deg)
    }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        transform: rotateY(180deg)
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(1turn);
        transform: rotateY(1turn)
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes loop-first {
    0% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    26% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    75% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    76% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}
@keyframes loop-first {
    0% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    26% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    75% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    76% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes loop-second {
    0% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    51% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0
    }
}
@keyframes loop-second {
    0% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    51% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes loop-third {
    0% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    26% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    75% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    76% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0
    }
}
@keyframes loop-third {
    0% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    26% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    75% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    76% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes loop-fourth {
    0% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    51% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}
@keyframes loop-fourth {
    0% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    51% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes loop-image-back {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        transform: rotateY(180deg)
    }
    25% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        transform: rotateY(180deg)
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(1turn);
        transform: rotateY(1turn)
    }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(1turn);
        transform: rotateY(1turn)
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(540deg);
        transform: rotateY(540deg)
    }
}
@keyframes loop-image-back {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        transform: rotateY(180deg)
    }
    25% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        transform: rotateY(180deg)
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(1turn);
        transform: rotateY(1turn)
    }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(1turn);
        transform: rotateY(1turn)
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(540deg);
        transform: rotateY(540deg)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and move your explanation out of code block.

Comment: Sure, but it's for the help to understand better for new developers. :)